# Android: how to add R.raw... to a method as a general parameter?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to create a method, to play some sound in different activities.

```
 public void playSound(View view, ??? sound){
        mpSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);
        mpSound.start();
    }
```

What type should have a "sound" parameter?

Answer (score 4):

Passing resource values can be `integers` like this:

```
public void playSound(View view, @RawRes int sound){
    mpSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, sound);
    mpSound.start();
}
```

Calling your method would be:

```
playSound(mView, R.raw.sound);
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be a int type with @RawRes Annotation like this:

```
public void playSound(View view, @RawRes int sound){
    mpSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, sound);
    mpSound.start();
}
```

You will see this error if you don't pass a raw resource:

```
Expected resource of type raw
```